# Not Showing DisplayName firebase Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Everything worked but not showing name only.

[image]

My code is:

```
user = profAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if (user != null) {

        // Name, email address
        String uid = user.getUid();
        String name = user.getDisplayName();
        String email = user.getEmail();
        txtName.setText(name);
        txtEmail.setText(email);
        txtUserid.setText(uid);
    }
```

Comment: maybe because your user has no name

Comment: It happens normally, when your provider is not `gmail` or`google+`. Check who is provider for user in firebase console.

Comment: i have used Email/password authentication?

Comment: when you create account using Email/password authentication the name will be empty , but you can change it

Comment: i have entered all details using object class

Comment: Takes `username` from user as a input, and save it in firebase realtime database. Then in your application access this username from realtime database not by `getDisplayname()`.

Comment: why? what for getDisplayName()

Comment: check the screen shot attached

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because Firebase Auth doesn't prompt the user to provide a Display name when signing up with Email/Password. But you can [do that manually](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#update_a_users_profile). Prompt the user to type the display name he desires, and pass it to the `setDisplayName()` method bellow:

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
        .setDisplayName(desiredName)
        .build();

user.updateProfile(profileUpdates)
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "User display name updated.");
                }
            }
        });
```